# Where are the source codes stored?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am a new ros user trying to get familiar with the environment. I am working with the husky mobile robot [package](https://github.com/husky/husky) and I am wondering, when I launch the gmapping_demo.launch file in husky_navigation, I know it launches gmapping.launch subsequently.

In the gmapping.launch file, it starts a node with the gmapping package.....my question is, where is the source code for gmapping actually stored in my computer?

I know that there is a gmapping package like [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping) available on github; however, I never installed this so how does my system know how to run gmapping with just installing the husky package? For example, in this package, there is a slam_gmapping/gmapping/src folder that contains the slam_gmapping.cpp file which I believe is the code that makes gmapping work. I am essentially trying to find the slam_gmapping.cpp from the slam_gmapping package in my computer.

I must be missing something ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295677/where-are-the-source-codes-stored?/) by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-28**:
Did you do the Desktop-full install?

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-28**:
yes I did desktop-full install

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-29**:
Simply do roscd to the package_name . It will take you to the directory and you will know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I can tell, the core of your question is "how can I find the source code of a package?"

#### Edit:

A quicker way to do this, as pointed out by @gvdhoorn, is to add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`:

```
+ deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

Then, you can run

```
sudo apt-get source ros-ROSDISTRO-PACKAGE
```

to download a copy of all of the source code to the current directory. Now that you have the source, follow step 4 to find the main.

#### Original:

Like Jayess mentioned, installing ROS packages from `apt` won't download the source code to your computer. This is something I've ran into several times before, and I have a quick and dirty procedure for it:

1. Figure out the name of the ROS package that I actually want to look at. In this case, you already know it's `gmapping`.
2. Find the package's page on http://wiki.ros.org. Usually a Google search brings this up. For `gmapping`, this page is http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping.
3. On the wiki, most packages link to their source code, usually right below the maintainer list (see the [MoveIt page](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit) for an example).  `gmapping` is unique in this case, because they are mostly external to ROS. However, they provide a link on their page to the [external documentation](https://openslam-org.github.io/gmapping.html), which contains a link to the [Github source code](https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping).
4. Now that you're at the source code, you probably want to find some launch file, so you follow the code from the beginning. Again, `gmapping` is unique because they aren't a native ROS project.  At this point, I just had to do some smart Googling to find the real [Github](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping), specifically for the ROS gmapping code. Now, going to the [launch file](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/launch/slam_gmapping_pr2.launch#L3), we see that it starts a single node, named `slam_gmapping`.  This is the name of the executable started, so if we go over to the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/CMakeLists.txt#L14), we see that this executable is compiled from `slam_gmapping.cpp` and `main.cpp`. Now you're at the start of the code!

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:
Slightly more 'official' and/or appropriate way to do this: [wiki/DebianPackageSources](http://wiki.ros.org/DebianPackageSources).

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2018-07-02**:
Thanks gvdhoorn! I've updated the answer to use your clearly less convoluted solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
The biggest advantage I feel is that you get the sources that correspond to whatever binary you have installed / is the currently released version for your platform.

**Comment by [burakaksoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38717/burakaksoy/) on 2018-11-28**:
After editing the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list , do not forget apt-get update. Otherwise apt-get will not be able to locate ROS packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You obviously *did* install `gmapping` because you're using it! I'm guessing that you did the Desktop-full install. If that's the case, just check what packages the [install page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1) says are installed

> Desktop-Full Install: (Recommended) : ROS, rqt, rviz, robot-generic libraries, 2D/3D simulators, navigation and **2D/3D perception**

From the above quote (emphasis is mine), you can see that `ros-perception` is added, [which contains `gmapping`](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping).

It's also listed as a [dependency in the package that you linked to](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/kinetic-devel/husky_navigation/package.xml#L23), so if you installed the `husky` package via `apt`, then `gmapping` would have been installed too.

---

**Update:**

You linked to the source. As far as I know you're not going to find the source on your computer (unless you compiled it manually). If you install something using `apt` you're installing a binary, not putting the source on your computer. If you want to read the source you should look at the repository that stores the source.

---

**Update 2:**

So, I double checked and you can find some headers in

`/opt/ros/<distro>/include`

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-28**:
I know that gmapping is installed because I am using it but I do not know where the file is stored. I'd like to find the slam_gmapping.cpp in my computer so that I can read the code that makes gmapping work

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-28**:
my question applies to other pkg's as well, where does ros store the source codes of these fundamental pkgs to make them work?